# Filter by attribute dynamicly in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of Javascript object, that i map throuh to display in a table

A long with that i have a pagination, component, that has an eventhandler in my main App.js component

```
onPageChanged = data => {
const { countries } = this.state;
const { currentPage, totalPages, pageLimit } = data;

const offset = (currentPage - 1) * pageLimit;
const currentCountries = countries.slice(offset, offset + pageLimit);

this.setState({ currentPage, currentCountries, totalPages });

 };
```

here i pass in the value, that i use to display the amoun of elements on each page, and the current page etc.

I have a filter method to filter by region

```
sortRegion = () =>{
   const newCountries =this.state.currentCountries.filter(country => 
   country.region === this.state.region);
   console.log(this.state.region)
   console.log(newCountries)
   this.setState({currentCountries: newCountries})
  }
```

as of now, i have an input form, with a onChange handler to change the state, of the `region` property

```
   {this.state.countries &&
      <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Get Region" value={this.state.region}  onChange={(e) => {this.setState({region: e.target.value)}}/>
      <button onClick={this.sortRegion}>Get country by Regions</button>
    <Pagination
     totalRecords={this.state.countries.length}
     pageLimit={4}
     pageNeighbours={1}
     onPageChanged={this.onPageChanged}
     />
     </div>
      }
```

This works fine when i press the button, but i want it to be dynamic, so it sorts whenever something is changed.

My inital though was to pass in a callback to setState to call the handler, but this does not show any results

```
          <input type="text" placeholder="Get Region" value={this.state.region}  onChange={(e) => {this.setState({region: e.target.value}, this.sortRegion)}}/>
```

how can i make the sorting dynamic, so it works onChange inside the form?